# Reference of this Hadith

Tags: hadith, reference-request

> Looking into the face of a brother in faith with love for the sake of Allah is better than the reward for itikaf (staying for the purpose of worshiping Allah) in my mosque for forty years.
>
> from "Benevolence of the Righteous" by Ahmad-Afandi

Comment: نظر الرجل إلى أخيه على شوق خير من اعتكاف سنة في مسجدي هذا It is weak.

Comment: Can you link where is this from?